# AWS EC2 - Get access logs of AWS EC2 Instance logged in by RDP

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp

I have created a windows instance and got .rdp file. How can i get the access logs i.e WHO and WHEN the instance is logged into with this .rdp file. Also, how much time was it used. Need help with the approaches of how to achieve this.

Comment: This is a Windows question. It is unrelated to the fact that the Windows machine is running on Amazon EC2. You might find a better response at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/about) since StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that possible completely to get each events log using Cloudwatch log Agent and system manager service which work on SSM Agents but this will work for Instances have Outbound Access to send logs to Cloudwatch. and the best part is AWS have amazing documentation for the same to setup a Cloudwatch for Windows Instances . [Please have a look on this Windows logs with Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartWindows2016.html)

I have myself setup it for Windows server as per the need we can be flexible. let me know if you stuck while following this document.

This is one of the best approach .